# PG::ConnectionBad: PQsocket() can't get socket descriptor - Sinatra

Tags: postgresql, sinatra, postgresql-9.3

Everytime I encounter this error, I manually go and restart the connection. How can I have Sinatra automatically reconnect to Postgre database after a DB disconnect?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language. In ruby, you can use the following

```
begin
  connect to db
rescue PG::ConnectionBad => ex
  retry
end
```

You can also put something into the rescue area which forces a re-connection. It's up to you depending on your needs.